# Why does Github API only returns the first 100 watched repositories?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm watching 392 repositories on Github. However, the Github API only returns 100. Does anyone have any idea why?

https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to paginate manually using the `page` parameter. The HTTP Response headers will tell you the next and the last page, if available. Check the headers:

- `X-Next`
- `X-Last`

Examples:

```
curl -D- https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.4
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2011 08:24:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
ETag: "c597e396e9f17b91c5c5a7e462ba954f"
X-Next: https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor?page=2
X-Last: https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor?page=5
```

Now the 2nd page:

```
curl -D- https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor?page=2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.4
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2011 08:28:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
ETag: "c57d0e97e2062672cb3771467cf2abc7"
X-Next: https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor?page=3
X-Last: https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor?page=5
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58
X-Runtime: 353ms
Content-Length: 44966
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

And the last one:

```
curl -D- https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/watched/trivektor?page=5
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.4
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2011 08:28:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
ETag: "11ce44ebc229eab0dc31731b39e10dcf"
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 57
X-Runtime: 93ms
Content-Length: 7056
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

Answer (score 0):

Very common for API's to limit the size of a response object to protect against outliers.  Given that it's returning a round number, that suggests this is by design.  I don't see them discussing paging in their docs, so it might just be a hard cap.  Either way, you should just ping github.