# Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online): API only returns 100 results

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm developing a Git dashboard in which we can select repositories, and get branch stats based on the selected repositories.

The problem I'm facing is the API only returns 100 results.

**Endpoint**

```
https://{instance}/defaultcollection/git/repositories/{repository}/stats/branches[/{name}]?api-version={version}
```

Found here: [Stats documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/git/stats)

The limit also exists on commits, which isn't really a problem. Is there a way around this? There isn't anything documented for paging like the [GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786087/why-does-github-api-only-returns-the-first-100-watched-repositories)

There are many branches that we don't even need to consider, for example we have bug branches i.e. `bugs/123` But the endpoint doesn't offer a way of filter out branches (or it isn't documented.)

Has anyone else experienced this?

**Update**

I've added this request to [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/12924840-increase-results-add-filtering-to-git-stats-endp), if you're interested in this being implemented, then go ahead and add a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rest API for "Stats" return the latest 100 results by default. There isn't anyway to change it for now. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

But for "Commits", it should return the latest 1000 results and you can change the value by adding "$top={integer}" in the URL.

> Parameter Type    Default Notes
>
> $skip     integer 0       Number of commits to skip.
>
> $top      integer 1000    Number of commits to return.

Refer to this link for details: [Get a list of commits](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/commits)